# Flutter with VSCode shows not installed even though its installs

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I just getting with flutter. I have installed it along created a project successfully.

But when I try to run it fails.

Below is the output with flutter doctor -v

```
PS C:\android-app\flutter-app\flutter_first_app> flutter doctor -v
```

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v0.5.5-pre.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.461], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.5.5-pre.9 at C:\android-app\flutter
    • Framework revision 587569337e (7 hours ago), 2018-06-13 00:02:21 +0200
    • Engine revision a328531402
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.60.0.flutter-a5e41681e5

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Sreyah Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Sreyah Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    X Android license status unknown.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.24.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected devices (1 available)
    • XT1706 • HKE63YLL • android-arm • Android 6.0 (API 23)
```

I have installed the Flutter extension.
I tried uninstall and install a couple of time, but still the same result.

Comment: How does it fail? You haven't included any error message or information on what's actually going wrong so it's hard to answer this.

Comment: See my updated comment - the issue with doctor is a bug, I'm just pushing a fix :)

Comment: Same issue here. I didn't uninstall just reloaded the flutter extension, then restarted VS Code to no avail. Everything appears to work, just the flutter doctor hiccup.

Answer (score 6):

I think there are two issues here:

1. Doctor says you don't have the extension
2. Your project doesn't run

## 1 Doctor says you don't have the extension

This is a bug I've just fixed. Seems like VS Code may have started lower-casing the extension folders recently, and our test for them was case sensitive. The fix is in master but hasn't made the beta channel (as of 22nd June 2018).

Note: This check doesn't affect anything else, as long as the extension is installed this is just an issue with the doctor output.

## 2. Your project doesn't run

This is probably not related to the doctor output if you can see the extension in VS Code. You haven't included any info on the reason your app doesn't run (does it give an error? what do you see?) so it's hard to guess; but if you can provide that info I can take a stab.

If you haven't already, it's also worth running the project from the command line with `flutter run` to see if it works there, to see whether the issue is specific to VS Code or something else with your setup.

If if works from the command line then I would recommend opening an issue [on GitHub for the Dart-Code repo](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code) with more information and we can track it down from there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your VS Code if you have it installed, if not you can still install it from the link. Flutter internally use Dart language to build a mobile app. So you need to install this extension
2. Then open this link "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter" to install this extension.
3. After the installation run your flutter doctor -v to confirm.